# Add DayDream (screen saver) for Android TV to exists Android project

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to add Android TV support to an existing Android project I have, specifically adding Day Dream service to show a screen saver.

I've seems to add all the required things for the app to run on Android TV and I can even see my Dream Service under Screen Saver in settings but when I select it - it is not selected and under Screen saver, there is no name.

Any ideas what I've might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [3 years-old example for Android TV DayDream](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-daydream) and in there was my [missing piece](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-daydream/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L75): In the manifest, under the service description I had to add `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE"`.

Full service XML piece:

```
    <service
        android:name=".bouncer.BouncerDreamService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Bouncing Logo"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```